# WordPress and Advanced Custom Fields management, custom columns in dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, dashboard

You don't really get much information about ACF field groups on the group list within dashboard, only the title and the description.

This makes it difficult to manage field groups on a bigger site.

I've managed to add an **order** column using [this function](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/show-order-no-for-each-field-group/), but I'd also like a **position** column to display whether the group is *high after title*, *normal* or *side*.

Any ideas how to extend the function to get this working?

```
function acf_field_group_columns($columns) {
    $columns['menu_order'] = __('Order');
    return $columns;
  } // end function reference_columns
  add_filter('manage_edit-acf-field-group_columns', 'acf_field_group_columns', 20);

  function acf_field_group_columns_content($column, $post_id) {
    switch ($column) {
      case 'menu_order':
        global $post;
        echo '<strong>',$post->menu_order,'</strong>';
        break;
      default:
        break;
    } // end switch
  } // end function reference_columns_content
  add_action('manage_acf-field-group_posts_custom_column', 'acf_field_group_columns_content', 20, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`$columns = array(
'cb' => $columns['cb'],
'image' => __( 'Image' ),
'title' => __( 'Title' ),
'price' => __( 'Price', 'smashing' ),
'area' => __( 'Area', 'smashing' ),
);`
```

You have to setup something like this. and if this is more often requiement then start using admincolumns.com

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but the example code you provided is not relevant to adding custom columns to the ACF listing section of the dashboard. It's for adding columns to the native page/post listing sections which is much more straightforward. I also want to avoid using a plugin when all I need is one additional column.